# Create 3 Levels of relations with Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, database, advanced-custom-fields

I need to create this type of relation in Wordpress:

- A Catalog can have many Products
- A Product can have many Catalogs
- A Category can have many Products
- A Product can have only one Category

So when I click on the Catalog, I need to see all the Categories of the Products that I have linked with the Catalog.

E.g:

- Catalog 1 -> Product 1 [Category 1]
- Catalog 1 -> Product 2 [Category 1]
- Catalog 1 -> Product 3 [Category 2]
- Catalog 2 -> Product 2 [Category 1]

So in the frontend, when I click on Catalog 1, I should see the Categories:
- Category 1
- Category 2

Then when I click the Category 1 (of Catalog 1) I should see the Products:
- Product 1
- Product 2

If I click on Catalog 2, I should see the Categories:
- Category 1

Then when I click the Category 1 (of Catalog 2), I should see the Products:
- Product 2

How can I rapresent these relations on Wordpress + ACF?

Comment: Is the catalog as a custom taxonomy or a custom page?
or just a select input in metabox?

Comment: @Manyang for the moment is a custom post type, but If could be useful to resolve the problem, I can change it to a taxonomy. I'm on analysis phase for the moment, so I can do any change.

Comment: if you dont have problem to make catalog to taxonomy, it will be easier, because you now have a relationship between category and taxonomy through the product id

Comment: @Manyang yes, no problem to change a catalog from custom post type to taxonomy, but I haven't understood how can I get the categories that are linked to catalog throught products.

Comment: Wait i will give you answer

Answer (score 0):

I not try this, but I hope this working

```
function get_list_catalog_category_product(){
  //get all catalog
  $catalogs = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'catalogs_term',
    'hide_empty' => false
  ));

  if ( !empty($catalogs) ) :
  //make list catalog
  $output = '<ul>';

  foreach( $catalogs as $catalog ) {

      //write all catalog
      $output.= '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $catalog ).'">'.$catalog->name.'</a>';

      //find all product related the catalog
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'product_post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'catalogs_term',
                  'field'    => 'term_id',
                  'terms'    => $catalog->term_id
              )
          )
      );
      $products = get_posts( $args );

      //make array of category related the catalog
      $all_category = array();

      //make array of product divided by category related the catalog
      $product_by_cat = array();

      if ( !empty($products) ){
        foreach( $products as $product ) {

          //write every product html
          $products_html ='<li><a href="'.get_permalink($product->ID).'">'.$product->post_title.'</a></li>';

          //find all category of this product
          $product_categories = wp_get_object_terms( $product->ID,  'category' );
          if ( ! empty( $product_categories ) ) {
            foreach($product_categories as $product_category) {

                //write the product html in related category if category never created this code will create or if has been create product html just append
                if(isset($product_by_cat[$product_category->term_id])){
                  $product_by_cat[$product_category->term_id] .= $products_html;
                }else{
                  $product_by_cat[$product_category->term_id] = $products_html;
                }

                //push the category as category related to catalog
                array_push($all_category,$product_category->term_id);
            }
          }

          //remove duplicate category if a product has more than 1 category
          $all_category = array_unique($all_category);
        }
      }

      if ( !empty($all_category) ){
        $output.= '<ul>';
          foreach( $all_category as $the_category ) {
            //write category html in catalog
            $output.='<li><a href="'.get_term_link($the_category).'">'.get_term( $term_id, 'category' )->name.'</a></li>';

            //write all product html to the category
            $output.='<ul>'.$product_by_cat[$the_category].'</ul>';
          }
        $output.= '</ul>';
      }

      $output.= '</li>';
  }
  $output.='</ul>';
  echo $output;
  endif;
}
```